# Removing a package broke gnome-panel, how do I get it back?

Tags: gnome-panel

i have ubuntu 10.10 and i remove nspr4 package from synaptic (wrong!).
After that gnome-panel is disabled and i lost internet connection. i install libnspr-dev and libnsrp. But there are no gnome-panel. Do i need install gnome-panel?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say exactly which package you removed, but the only similar package installed on my machine is `libnspr4-0d`. It is a dependency of a bunch of stuff, so if you removed it, you'll have to reinstall a lot of things. `gnome-panel` is one such thing you'll have to reinstall.

I recommend, however, that you also reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` to hopefully get everything back. In the future, you shouldn't remove anything beginning with `lib` unless you know what you're doing or your package manager informs you that the lib is no longer needed.

By the way, you only need *-dev packages (such as `libnspr4-dev`) if you want to compile software from source that has a build-time dependency on that particular library.

Answer (score 0):

To identify what you've installed/deinstalled take a look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.